# Как получить id пользователя при обращении к слеш команде disnake

Tags: python, discord, disnake

Не знаю как получить id пользователя, вызвавшего слеш команду.(disnake)

```
    @bot.slash_command(name="sms")
    async def sms (inter, id: str, message: str):
        admin=00000000000000000
        if ctx.author.id == admin:
            user = bot.get_user(id)
            await user.send(message)
            await inter.response.send_message("Отправлено! ^^")
```

Answer (score 0):

В disnake вместо ctx.author.id нужно использовать inter.author.id. Также обратите внимание, что вы пытаетесь использовать аргумент id, который не передается в слеш-команду. Вместо этого, вам нужно использовать аргумент user: disnake.User, чтобы получить пользователя, которому нужно отправить сообщение.

Попробуйте изменить свой код следующим образом:

```
@bot.slash_command(name="sms")
async def sms(inter, user: disnake.User, message: str):
    admin = 00000000000000000  
    if inter.author.id == admin:
        await user.send(message)
        await inter.response.send_message("Отправлено! ^^")
```

теперь вы можете вызвать эту команду, указав пользователя и сообщение, которое нужно отправить. Например, /sms @user Привет!.